# DLIB and QT under windows. SVM multiclass training unlinked reference

Tags: c++, qt, dlib

I am trying to build the example provided by dlib for multiple class SVM training using QT on windows. (the example is available at this link: http://dlib.net/multiclass_classification_ex.cpp.html)

first of all I took the DLIB .lib files from a prebuilt library using MS visual studio, and took the include files and modified the QT .pro file to be as follows.

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/dlib/include
debug {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/dlib/lib -ldlib_debug_64bit_msvc1900
}

!debug {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/dlib/lib -ldlib_release_64bit_msvc1900
}
```

when i try building the code i get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::~thread_pool_implementation()'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::shutdown_pool()'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::thread_pool_implementation(unsigned long)'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::num_threads_in_pool() const'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::num_threads_in_pool() const'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::find_empty_task_slot() const'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::make_next_task_id(long)'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::wait_for_all_tasks() const'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::is_worker_thread(unsigned long) const'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::find_empty_task_slot() const'
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `dlib::thread_pool_implementation::~thread_pool_implementation()'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

knowing that i tried to run the simple SVM code (provided here: http://dlib.net/svm_ex.cpp.html) it compiled and ran perfectly.

Am I missing a library of some kind? as all the errors are linking error and undefined references?

Comment: Just guessing: try to include `dlib/all/source.cpp` too into your project.

Comment: Try: `CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/dlib/lib -ldlib_debug_64bit_msvc1900
}else {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/dlib/lib -ldlib_release_64bit_msvc1900
}` and make sure your compiler is MSVC++ 14.0 as the pre-built libraries.

Comment: i did the include of sources .cpp but i ended up getting the following errors:

    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\dlib\include\dlib\all\source.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp__getsockname@12'
    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SVMDlib\dlib\include\dlib\all\source.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp__inet_ntoa@4'

and several more errors of this type

Comment: did the config addition still got the same error

Comment: is your Qt compiler MSVC 14.0? If not it won't work. Compiler needs to be same as pre-built libraries.

Comment: `_imp_inetntoa@4` is a different error than you posted. Include the correct library on windows e. g. `#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")`